# How to separate data using Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can we separate the Business unit data in Marketing cloud?
Like I have a business unit A and B. I would want all the data in business unit A and Business unit B should contain data which have name value as "ABC".

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using data extensions -

Create your two business units - A and B. Define a Subscriber Filter, if you want to limit the All Subscribers lists in each business unit. You will need to Subscriber Filter using a define Profile Attribute.

At your Parent business unit, create your 'Master Data Extension' i.e. the DE that will contain all data for A and B.

Create two folders in Shared Data Extensions and set necessary sharing permissions for :
Business Unit A
Business Unit B

Copy/Create your Data Extension structure from the Master Data Extension - 1 copy for each business unit and store these in the Shared DE folder.

Create 2 SQL statements (Add to Automation studio) to select from the Master Data Extension, using criteria of selection for which Business Unit's data extension you want to import into. Save your results into the Data Extensions.

When you go into each business unit, you should then see under Shared Data Extensions the data extensions (and its data) relevant to that business unit.

If you have configured the Subscriber Filter correctly, then when you send to the data extension, the records get added to All Subscribers and based on the Subscriber Filter (profiled it's correct in your data extension) the All Subscribers list will then only show subscribers for that business unit.

Comment: I revoked the permissions for the new Business Unit created for All Subscribers and Subscribers for my user but still I'm able to view and use all the Subscribers in Business Unit. Can you tell why and how can I stop this because what I want to do is that the new Business unit should only contain the subscribers created or selected by me and not all Subscribers. Also, please can you tell me that how can we use the Business Unit filter attributes because I created one but I'm not able to filter the values based on this for the Business Unit.